# Magento 2 creating configuration articles programmatically

Tags: magento2

> I have some troubles with assigning simple or virtual products to a
>   configurable product in Magento 2 programmatically.
>
> The code I use is already from a Magento.StackExchange issue but it is
>   not working for me and am really confused already. Through my testing,
>   I use hardcoded variables. Simple products (future variants and
>   parent) are created manually. my code just runs the
>   createConfigurable() method once. Attribute code 93 is for color and
>   193 for size.  The Result is that I get a configurable product
>   (parent) but not assigned with the variations.

```
public function createConfigurable(){
    $attributeSetId = 9;
    $parentId = 161;
    $associatedProductIds = array(157,158);//Simple Product ids array
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($parentId); // Load Configurable Product
    $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
    $position = 0;
    $attributes = array(93,139); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product(list of supper attribute ids what ever belong to that the attribute set under which the configurable product is)

    foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
        $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $parentId, 'position' => $position);
        $position++;
        $attributeModel->setData($data);//->save();
    }
    $output->writeln(var_dump($data));
    $product->setTypeId("configurable");
    $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes($attributeSetId);
    $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
    $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
    $product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->save();
}
```

> hope someone has ideas to solve this issue!
>
> thank you